# Testing ThreadLocal member variables

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-local

I have been trying to verify if the ThreadLocal members are indeed different in different threads.

This is my TestClass whose object I am sharing among multiple threads.

```
public class TestClass {

    private static Set<Integer> setI;

    private static ThreadLocal<Set<String>> setS;



    public TestClass() {

            Set<String> temp = new HashSet<String>();

            for (int i=0; i<=4; i++) {

                    setI.add(i);

                    temp.add(Integer.toString(i));

            }

            setS.set(temp);

    }


    static {

            setI = new HashSet<Integer>();

            setS = new ThreadLocal<Set<String>>() {

                    protected Set<String> initialValue() {

                            return new HashSet<String>();

                    }

            };

    }



    public static void addToIntegerSet(int i) {

            synchronized(setI) {

                    setI.add(i);

            }

   }



    public static void addToStringSet(String str) {

            Set<String> sets = setS.get();

            sets.add(str);

            setS.set(sets);

    }

}
```

the following is the class I use to test this out :-

```
package personal;



import java.util.*;

import personal.TestClass;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;



public class Test2 {



        private static TestClass testObj;

        private static Set<Set<String>> testStringSet;

        private static Set<Set<Integer>> testIntegerSet;



        static {

                testObj = new TestClass();

                testStringSet = new HashSet<Set<String>>();

                testIntegerSet = new HashSet<Set<Integer>>();

        }



        private static void addToStringSet(Set<String> sets) {

                synchronized(testStringSet) {

                        testStringSet.add(sets);

               }

        }



        private static void addToIntegerSet(Set<Integer> sets) {

                synchronized(testIntegerSet) {

                        testIntegerSet.add(sets);

                }

        }



        private static int getTestIntegerSetSize() {

                synchronized(testIntegerSet) {

                        return testIntegerSet.size();

                }

        }



        private static int getTestStringSetSize() {

                synchronized(testStringSet) {

                        return testStringSet.size();

                }

        }



        private static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

                private TestClass tc;

                private String name;

                public MyRunnable(TestClass tc, int i) {

                        this.name = "Thread:- " + Integer.toString(i);

                        this.tc = tc;

                }

                @Override

                public void run() {

                        try {

                                Field f1 = tc.getClass().getDeclaredField("setS");

                                Field f2 = tc.getClass().getDeclaredField("setI");

                                f1.setAccessible(true);

                                f2.setAccessible(true);

                                Set<String> v1 = (Set<String>)(((ThreadLocal<Set<String>>)(f1.get(tc))).get());

                                Set<Integer> v2 = (Set<Integer>) f2.get(tc);

                                addToIntegerSet(v2);

                                addToStringSet(v1);

                        } catch (Exception exp) {

                                System.out.println(exp);

                        }

                }

        }



        public static void main(String[] args) {

                for (int i=1; i<=2; i++) {

                        (new Thread (new MyRunnable(testObj,i))).start();

                }

                try {

                        Thread.sleep(5);                       

                } catch (Exception exp) {

                        System.out.println(exp);

                }

                System.out.println(getTestStringSetSize());

                System.out.println(getTestIntegerSetSize());

        }



}
```

thus the 1st print statement should print out 2 and the second one should print out 1.

how ever the 1st print statement also prints out 1.

what is wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

For a test class, I'd start with something much, much simpler.  Just store a String or something in the ThreadLocal to start with, and avoid the reflection calls (setAccessible, etc.).  Your issue is most likely in all of this extra code, and nothing due to the ThreadLocal itself.